# Clang with MinGW STL (Error: no member named 'fgetws' in the global namespace)

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors, mingw, clang

I'm trying to compile a simple dll with Clang under windows using the MinGW STL (latest versions for clang and mingw). As you can see, I have disabled ms compatibility mode and the hardcoded VS headers. I get the following errors when I include the MinGW STL map header:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\vc11\bin\Debug>clang++ -fno-ms-compatibility -nostdinc -c -shared -v -o simple.o simple.cpp -I "C:\MinGW\include\sys" -I "C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\4.8.0\include" -I "C:\MinGW\include" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\backward" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\bits" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\debug" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\decimal" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\ext" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\i686-pc-mingw32" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\tr1" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\tr2" -I "C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\profile" -Wl,--verbose
clang version 3.4 (trunk)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
clang++.exe: warning: -Wl,--verbose: 'linker' input unused
clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-shared'
 "C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/vc11/bin/Debug/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name simple.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -v -coverage-file simple.o -nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc -resource-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/vc11/bin/Debug\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.4" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\sys" -I "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\i686-pc-mingw32\\4.8.0\\include" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\backward" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\bits" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\debug" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\decimal" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\ext" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\i686-pc-mingw32" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\tr1" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\tr2" -I "C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\4.8.0\\profile" -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 150 -mstackrealign -fms-extensions -fmsc-version=1300 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -backend-option -vectorize-loops -o simple.o -x c++ simple.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target i686-pc-win32
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\MinGW\include\sys
 C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\4.8.0\include
 C:\MinGW\include
 C:\MinGW\include\c++
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\backward
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\bits
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\debug
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\decimal
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\ext
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\i686-pc-mingw32
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\tr1
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\tr2
 C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\profile
End of search list.
In file included from simple.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\map:61:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\bits/stl_map.h:63:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\tuple:39:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\array:38:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\stdexcept:39:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\string:40:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\bits/char_traits.h:40:
In file included from C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\bits/postypes.h:40:
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:143:11: error: no member named 'fgetws' in the global namespace
  using ::fgetws;
        ~~^
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:145:11: error: no member named 'fputws' in the global namespace
  using ::fputws;
        ~~^
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:149:11: error: no member named 'getwc' in the global namespace
  using ::getwc;
        ~~^
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:150:11: error: no member named 'getwchar' in the global namespace
  using ::getwchar;
        ~~^
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:155:11: error: no member named 'putwc' in the global namespace
  using ::putwc;
        ~~^
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.0\cwchar:156:11: error: no member named 'putwchar' in the global namespace
  using ::putwchar;
        ~~^
6 errors generated.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are declared in MinGW's `stdio.h` and/or `wchar.h` when the `__MSVCRT__` macro is defined.  The MinGW compiler defines `__MSVCRT__` when it's building agains the `msvcrt.dll` runtime instead of the older `crtdll` runtime (which I think is pretty much never used anymore).

I don't know if clang would define that macro or under what conditions it would (or even if clang will link to `msvcrt.dll`).

You might try adding a `-D__MSVCRT__=1` to the clang command line to see if that makes things work.